# Browser displays Apache Test page when accessing website with a domain name I have just registered

Tags: ubuntu, website, domain-name, htaccess

My website is **deployed** on **Tomcat** which in turn in deployed on **Ubuntu** server.
While developing the website I access it using server IP address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080:/yyyy. Now I have bought a **domain name** and did a step to redirect www.mydomain.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. When I try to access my wesite via www.mydomain.com I get Apache Test Page. Could someone **provide link** or **explain remaining steps** I need to take to be able to reach my website?

Comment: Change "8080" to "80" - - https://stackoverflow.com/q/18415578/3395469

Comment: Are you using port 80 (or default) when using  www.mydomain.com? Is you app properly deployed on the Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a help of:

> Almost perfect solution for me but port forwarding had to be done
>   differently:
>   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-access-a-java-web-application-by-a-domain-name-using-tomcat-8
>
> About port forwarding:
>   https://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/
>
> With a help of this article and the post of Robert Goley I figured the
>   port "forwarding" commands I actually needed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104824/port-forward-to-a-port-on-the-same-machine

So it all came to these steps:

1. Stopping **Apache2** server on my **Ubuntu**
2. Editing **Host** config in the **Tomcat's server.xml** to look like:

   ```
    <Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
         <Alias>www.mydomain.com</Alias>
         <Context path="" docBase="mydomain_appname" debug="0" privileged="true" />
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/></Host>
   ```
3. Then I ran these commands but **latter deleted** the rules I saw in the iptables (don't know how much of an impact rules 1 and 3 had):

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to XXXXX:8080

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d XXXXX --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

4. And finally I ran:

sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80-j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 80-j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

**In the end:** now I can access my website with www.mydomain.com as any other website. Port 8443 remains in the URL when I acces secure pages though. Need to fix that.